# Treating iPad's `Return` as `Tab`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad

How can I cause the `return` key on the iPad's keyboard to behave as the `tab` key when in an HTML form?

My current solution is this:

```
$('input[type=text]').keydown(function(e)
{
  if (e.keyCode == 13)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).nextAll('input[type=text]:first').focus();
  }
});
```

I found this solution in the link below, which works in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfBNE/) included in the comments of the answer.

- [jQuery how to make Enter (Return) act as Tab key through input text fields but in the end trigger the submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835008/jquery-how-to-make-enter-return-act-as-tab-key-through-input-text-fields-but-i)

This solution is not working in my case though (on iPad or PC).  Based on the comments, I think it might be my HTML structure that is causing trouble though I am not sure how I could alter it to achieve the same layout.

How else can I cause the `return` key to jump to the next input field?

My form's HTML block is below (skip to avoid long HTML read):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6">
    <div class="control-group" id="GuestName_group">
      <label class="control-label" for="textbox_Name"><i class="icon-user"></i> Guest Name</label>
      <div class="controls controls-row">
        <input type="text" class="span6" id="textbox_Name" data-provide="typeahead"  placeholder="Lastname, Firstname">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="textbox_Group"><i class="icon-home"></i> Organization</label>
      <div class="controls controls-row">
        <input type="text" class="span6" id="textbox_Group" placeholder="Organization">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="span6">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="select_Host"><i class="icon-star"></i> AOELab Host Name</label>
      <div class="controls controls-row">
        <select class="span6" id="select_Host">
          {% for person in host_names %}
          <option value="{{ person.bems }}">{{ person.name }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="textarea_Purpose"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i> Purpose</label>
      <div class="controls controls-row">
        <label class="radio inline">
          <input type="radio" name="optionsPurpose" id="radio_Purpose1" value="meeting" checked>
          Meeting
        </label>
        <label class="radio inline">
          <input type="radio" name="optionsPurpose" id="radio_Purpose2" value="tour">
          Tour
        </label>
        <label class="radio inline">
          <input type="radio" name="optionsPurpose" id="radio_Purpose3" value="other">
          Other...
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="controls controls-row">
        <textarea class="span6" id="textarea_Purpose" placeholder="Why are you here?"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you want to? There are  "prev/next" buttons above the keyboard that are explicitly intended for that purpose.

Comment: Because, though user testing, we've found that users generally expect the `return` key to advance to the next selection.  The form is not submitted through standard means (on purpose) so causing the system to behave inline with user expectations is the goal.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=text]').on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var tabables = $("*[tabindex != '-1']:visible"),
             index = tabables.index(this);

        tabables.eq(index + 1).focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kuefx/)